# mongodb (>=1.4.1) and php: connection pooling

Tags: php, mongodb, connection-pooling

Is connection pooling with a actual php mongo driver (>= 1.4.1) possible? The Mongo and MongoPool Classes are deprecated or not implemented in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP MongoDB driver does persistent connections, not connection pooling, as of the 1.3.0 release.

The MongoPool class is only kept around for few minor versions in case people were using them, and we didn't want to break peoples code "just because". It is however scheduled for removal soon, so if you see an application that uses it.. Please remove it :)

The Mongo class is deprecated, and you should use the MongoClient class.
This is due to the fact we want to have WriteConcern enabled by default, which we couldn't do without "maybe" breaking peoples code that were using the Mongo class.

Now, for pooling vs persistence, the PHP architecture doesn't work well with connection pooling - thats just not beneficial in PHP. However, persistent connections make much sense and will do all you need from "connection pooling" in reality.